# Require.js default scheme like /lib/module/module.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Is it possible to set some option in require.js to allow the default scheme to include a sub-directory with the module name?

I want to write...

```
require(["underscore","jquery"],function(_,$){
    // do something here
})
```

And I want it to find jquery and underscore in this folder structure...

```
/
/lib/
    /jquery/
           /jquery.js
    /underscore/
           /underscore.js
```

Currently, I have to write...

```
require(["/lib/underscore/underscore","/lib/jquery/jquery"],function(_,$){
    // do something here
})
```

Or some crazy wrapper...

```
function req(arr,cb){
  require(arr.join().replace(/(\w+)/g,function(mod){ return "/lib/"+mod+"/"+mod }).split(","),cb)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should work with the stating this in the `requirejs.config` - function, like this:

```
requirejs.config({
    //By default load any module IDs from js/lib
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',

    //except, if the module ID starts with "app",
    //load it from the js/app directory. paths
    //config is relative to the baseUrl, and
    //never includes a ".js" extension since
    //the paths config could be for a directory.
    paths: {
        app: '../app'
    }
});
```

[Taken from the Require.js API-docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles), so in the `paths` - property you could specify all paths for the libraries you'll want to use

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [paths config option](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths) to add the paths the way you want.

```
var libPaths = (function() {
  var libs = ["jquery", "underscore"];

  var lib, paths = {};
  for(var i=0; i < libs.length; i++) {
    lib = libs[i];
    paths[lib] = "/lib/" + lib + "/" + lib;
  }
  return paths;
})();

requirejs.config({
  paths: libPaths
});
```

To add more overrides, simply add to the `libs` array.